# Find the limit of the given sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+3^n+\dots +2012^n}$$

I have used the Squeeze theorem (or the Sandwich theorem):

$$n\cdot \sqrt[n]{1^n}\le\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+3^n+\dots +2012^n}\le n\cdot \sqrt[n]{2012^n}$$
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \sqrt[n]{1^n} = \infty$
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \sqrt[n]{2012^n} = \infty$
thus the limit of that sequence equals $\infty$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limit is $2012$.

Let $x_n$ denote the $n$th term, then $2012=\sqrt[n]{2012^n}\leqslant x_n\leqslant\sqrt[n]{2012\cdot2012^n}=2012\cdot\sqrt[n]{2012}$ where $\sqrt[n]{2012}\to1$. We are done.

Answer (score 8):

$$2012=\sqrt[n]{2012^n}\le\sqrt[n]{1^n+2^n+3^n+\dots +2012^n}\le \sqrt[n]{2012\cdot 2012^n}= 2012\sqrt[n]2012$$
Now applying Sandwich Theorem we have the limiting value to be 2012 (as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]2012=1$)

Comment: The second inequality is false for every small $n$, namely, for approximately every $n\leqslant45$.

Comment: Thanks @did for pointing out the mistake , now i think it is correct.

Comment: [Excellent idea](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/293491/6179), now this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the above answers - we can generalize the obtained result. If $k$ is a natural number, and $0\leq x_{1}\leq x_{2}\leq ...\leq x_{k}$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_{1}^{n}+x_{2}^{n}+...+x_{k}^{n}}=x_{k}.$$

Indeed, the following inequalities hold:

$$x_{k}=\sqrt[n]{x_{k}^{n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{x_{1}^{n}+x_{2}^{n}+...+x_{k}^{n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{k\cdot x_{k}^{n}}=x_{k}\cdot\sqrt[n]{k}.$$

Since we know that $\sqrt[n]{k}\to 1$, our result follows from the squeeze theorem.