limit of a sequence with parameters
Find the limit of the folowing sequences:

$a_n=\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$

I am thinking that if :
$a,b$ $\in$ $(0,1)$ then the limit is equal to $0$;
$a$ $\in$ $(0,1)$ and $b>1$ the limit will be equal to $b$;
$a,b$ $\in$ $(1,\infty)$, we will get $\infty$ if $a\neq b$ and $a$ if $a=b$
Is this ok or I am missing something?

$a_n=\sqrt[n]{a_{1}^n+a_{2}^n+...+a_{p}^n}$, $a_1,a_2,...,a_p>0$

For this one I was thinking that $\sqrt[n]{a_{p}^n}<a_n$, and the limit will be $a_p$ but I can't find something that is greater than $a_n$ that is going to the same value.
Thx!

Are you assuming that $a,b >0$? If that is the case, note that $a_n \ge a$ and $a_n \ge b$ for all $n$. Also, $a_n \le \sqrt[n]{2} \max(a,b)$.

If $0 \leq a \leq b$, then $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{b^n+b^n} = \sqrt[n]{2}b$ and $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} \geq \sqrt[n]{b^n} = b$.

Oh, my bad, $a,b$ $\in$ $(0,\infty)$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/293507

thx, it s very easy actually

Since you agreed, I voted to close as a duplicate.
